# Count number of objects in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I want to query the number of users, groups, and OUs in any given Active Directory.

Doing this by using a [`DirectorySearcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) and counting the number of results (as all the advice I found while researching this problem is suggesting) would be very slow on larger directories. Is there any way to query a property that holds this information directly? (similar to the row count property in SQL)

If there is only a property for all objects that's fine, though I prefer getting each individually.

Comment: You have to count them manually. You can try using classes from System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace. They should work slightly faster than DirectorySearcher. Also query only certain attributes for an object which decreases the amount of network traffic and increases performance.